# Rails 4 - association not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, associations

I created 2 models using a rails generator like this:

> $ bin/rails g model manager name:string

and

> $ bin/rails g model blog/post title:string manager:references

With that, I have 2 models files:

```
# app/models/manager.rb
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :blog_posts
end
```

and

```
# app/models/blog/post.rb
class Blog::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :manager
end
```

going to the rails console I can create a manager and a post like this:

> $ manager1 = Manager.new
>   $ manager1.name = "John Doe"
>   $ manager1.save
>   $ post1 = Blog::Post.new
>   $ post1.title = "Hello World"
>   $ post1.manager = manager1
>   $ post1.save

And on console, if I do:

> $ post1.manager.name

that works perfectly. Returning the Manager's name. But if I do:

> $ manager1.blog_posts

I expected to get the list of manager's posts. But I am getting this error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Manager::BlogPost

The same happing when I try to do Many-to-Relationship between "Blog:Category (app/models/blog/category)" and "Blog::Post (app/models/blog/post.rb)"

### UPDATE

@Pavan solved my first problem... And based in that solution, I tried to do the this:

```
# app/models/blog/post.rb
class Blog::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :manager
    has_and_belongs_to_many :blog_categories, class_name: 'Blog::Category', foreign_key: 'blog_category_id'
end
```

and:

```
# app/models/blog/category.rb
class Blog::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :blog_posts, class_name: 'Blog::Post', foreign_key: 'blog_post_id'
end
```

And based on that `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association`, I generate the following migration:

```
class CreateBlogCategoriesPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :blog_categories_posts, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :blog_post, index: true
      t.belongs_to :blog_category, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

But when I try this on console:

> $ post1 = Blog::Post.first
>   $ post1.blog_categories

I got this error:

> 2.2.2 :002 > p.blog_categories PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column blog_categories_posts.category_id does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...log_categories_posts" ON "blog_categories"."id" = "blog_cate...
>                                                                ^ : SELECT "blog_categories".* FROM "blog_categories" INNER JOIN
>   "blog_categories_posts" ON "blog_categories"."id" =
>   "blog_categories_posts"."category_id" WHERE
>   "blog_categories_posts"."blog_category_id" = $1
>   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column
>   blog_categories_posts.category_id does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...log_categories_posts" ON "blog_categories"."id" = "blog_cate...
>                                                                ^ : SELECT "blog_categories".* FROM "blog_categories" INNER JOIN
>   "blog_categories_posts" ON "blog_categories"."id" =
>   "blog_categories_posts"."category_id" WHERE
>   "blog_categories_posts"."blog_category_id" = $1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NameError: uninitialized constant Manager::BlogPost

You have `has_namy :blog_posts` defined in `manager.rb`, so Rails will look for a `classname` `BlogPost` which isn't exist in your case.

You should explicitly specify the `classname` to tell Rails to use it.

```
# app/models/manager.rb
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blog_posts, class_name: 'Blog::Post'
end
```

Comment: I did that first... but I think I didn't restarted the console. Now is working... I will try to use the same with Many-To-Many Relations. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Pavan, I was testing something first... please see my update